# CSS Table - How to make <th> overlaping element above and keep it center based on content

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am building this nightmarish table and there is this kind of **table header**
[See Image One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL0lm.png)

And I would like to keep the **table header** to be overlapping the title in the center with the split line even when the text gets to 2 lines.
[See Image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXazq.png)

Thanks for the strong texthelp!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of  what you have to date

Answer (score 0):

It needs a bit of tweaking, but here's something I hope gets you set in the right direction:

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.1 );
    
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
table caption {
    
}

table thead {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

table thead th {
    
}
table thead th span {
    display: block;
    background-color: navy;
    position: relative;
    top: 2em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.25em;
}

table tbody {
    
}

table tbody td {
    padding: 1em;
}

table tbody td {
    text-align: center;
}

table tbody tr:first-child td {
    padding-top: 2em;
}

table tbody tr:not(:last-child) td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
<caption>How many pay periods are in a year?</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th><span>Pay schedule</span></th>
    <th><span>Number of pay periods in a year</span></th>
    <th><span>Number of pay periods in a year</span></th>
    <th><span>Number of pay periods in a year</span></th>
    <th><span>Pay schedule</span></th>
    <th><span>Pay schedule</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>Weekly</td>
    <td>52</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.. I am a full beginner (doing most of the things in Webflow) does this solution works with the overlap? Check here if it wasn't really understandable from the image before -> https://imgur.com/a/VBiVtr8

Problem is.. if the header gets to 3 lines I would still like to keep it centered like this. 

Thanks for the additional info

Answer (score 0):

Technically, using the caption tag is better, but knowing how to absolutely position element is useful, so take a look at the following:

```css
table {
  position: relative;
}
table thead th div {
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table style="position: relative">
  <thead>
    <th>
      <div>
        table heading
      </div>
      1st column
    </th>
    <th>
      2nd column
    </th>
    <th>
      3rd column
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1st td
      </td>
      <td>
        2nd td
      </td>
      <td>
        3r td
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div style="margin-top: 50px" />
<table style="position: relative">
  <thead>
    <th>
      <div>
        table heading
      </div>
      1st column
    </th>
    <th>
      2nd column
    </th>
    <th>
      3rd column
    </th>
    <th>
      4th column
    </th>
    <th>
      5th column
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1st td
      </td>
      <td>
        2nd td
      </td>
      <td>
        3rd td
      </td>
      <td>
        4th td
      </td>
      <td>
        5th td
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The absolute positioned div within the first th causes it to position within the table, but the table should be set to explicitly position to work.